# wso2esb LDAP connector retrive thumbnailphoto

Tags: ldap, wso2, wso2-esb

How can I retrieve thumbnailphoto from Active Directory using LDAP Connector in WSO2ESB?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use search[1] operation to retrieve the thumbnailphoto and we have to specify the attributes[2] (jpegPhoto or thumbnailPhoto).

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+CRUD+operations+in+LDAP#WorkingwithCRUDoperationsinLDAP-searchEntry

[2] https://kanboard.net/documentation/ldap-profile-picture